# How to Copy/Insert All Elements of A Slide Within the Same Presentation

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write code that will take a slide and all of the elements on that slide, and duplicate it in another location in the same Slides presentation.

With my current code, I am able to get it to copy the slide over, but not the individual elements.

```
function summaryslide() {
  var doc = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var docId = doc.getId();
  var copysrcSlideIndex = 1;
  var copydstSlideIndex = 6;
  var srcSlide = SlidesApp.getFileById(docId).getSlides[copysrcSlideIndex];
  SlidesApp.getFileById(docId).insertSlide(copydstSlideIndex);
}
```

I need to 2 things to happen.  I need to be able to copy over the entire slide to the next to last slide.  There are 2 caveats to doing it though that I hope are solvable.  The elements will likely not be the same each time, as this slide will be modified each time it's used.  The number of slides in the presentation will likely be changing each time it's used.  (The current code is based on a fixed number of slides.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Slide.duplicate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#duplicate()) and [Slide.move()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#move(Integer)) methods as shown below:

```
// Argument index starts with 0 for the first slide
// This is a source slide for duplicating
function duplicateSlideByIndex(index) {
  var p = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = p.getSlides()[index].duplicate();  // duplicated slide
  slide.move(p.getSlides().length);
}
```